# Blackberry ActivityIndicator not seen during Http Connection

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection, activity-indicator

I have written the underlying code to display an activityindicator while a hhtp connection call is made. Unfortunately, the activity indicator does not appear on the screen till the http connection call is complete. Hence it is not serving its purpose.

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
                {
                  public void run()
                  {

                       ActivityIndicatorView view = new ActivityIndicatorView(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
                        ActivityIndicatorModel model = new ActivityIndicatorModel();
                        ActivityIndicatorController controller = new ActivityIndicatorController();

                        view.setController(controller);
                        view.setModel(model);

                        controller.setModel(model);
                        controller.setView(view);

                        model.setController(controller);        

                        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("spinner.png");
                        view.createActivityImageField(bitmap, 5, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

                        _activityFieldManager.add(view);
                          UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().invalidate();

                  }
                });
                //SyncWithDB is the Class that makes the Http connection call
                new SyncWithDB();
                _activityFieldManager.delete(view);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().invalidate();
                Dialog.inform("Sync Complete");
```

As suggested I even tried

```
view = new ActivityIndicatorView(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
                ActivityIndicatorModel model = new ActivityIndicatorModel();
                ActivityIndicatorController controller = new ActivityIndicatorController();

                view.setController(controller);
                view.setModel(model);

                controller.setModel(model);
                controller.setView(view);

                model.setController(controller);        

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("spinner.png");
                view.createActivityImageField(bitmap, 5, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

                _activityFieldManager.add(view);
                  UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().invalidate();

                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
                {
                  public void run()
                  {

                      try {
                        new SyncWithDB();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                });


                _activityFieldManager.delete(view);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().invalidate();
                Dialog.inform("Sync Complete");
```

But the result remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using invokeAndWait(), are you performing the HTTP operation in a worker thread?  If not, you should be.  The ActivityIndicator should be managed in the main dispatch thread, and the HTTP operation managed in a worker thread.

For example:

```
view = new ActivityIndicatorView(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
ActivityIndicatorModel model = new ActivityIndicatorModel();
ActivityIndicatorController controller = new ActivityIndicatorController();

view.setController(controller);
view.setModel(model);

controller.setModel(model);
controller.setView(view);

model.setController(controller);        

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("spinner.png");
view.createActivityImageField(bitmap, 5, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

_activityFieldManager.add(view);
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().invalidate();

Thread thread = new Thread()
{
  public void run()
  {
    try {
      new SyncWithDB();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(
      new Runnable()
      {
        protected void run()
        {
          _activityFieldManager.delete(view);
          UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().invalidate();
          Dialog.inform("Sync Complete");
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
thread.start();
```

Or, a little more generically:

```
ActivityIndicatorView view;
ActivityFieldManager _activityFieldManager;

class SyncFinished extends Runnable
{
  public void run()
  {
    _activityFieldManager.delete(view);
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().invalidate();
    Dialog.inform("Sync Complete");
  }
}

class SyncThread extends Thread
{
  Runnable runWhenFinished;

  public SyncThread(Runnable r)
  {
    super();
    runWhenFinished = r;
  }

  public void run()
  {
    try {
      new SyncWithDB();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (runWhenFinished != null)
      UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(runWhenFinished);
  }
}

view = new ActivityIndicatorView(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
ActivityIndicatorModel model = new ActivityIndicatorModel();
ActivityIndicatorController controller = new ActivityIndicatorController();

view.setController(controller);
view.setModel(model);

controller.setModel(model);
controller.setView(view);

model.setController(controller);        

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("spinner.png");
view.createActivityImageField(bitmap, 5, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

_activityFieldManager.add(view);
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().invalidate();

SyncThread thread = new SyncThread(new SyncFinished());
thread.start();
```

Comment: Hi Remy
I tried your suggestion, but it did not help. The problem persists.
Could you please suggest something else.
Regards

Comment: Hi Remy, Please see the updated(second) part of my query. I suppose this is what you suggested.

Comment: Closer, but not quite there yet.  Don't use `invokeAndWait()`.  That is forcing the HTTP code to still run within the event dispatching thread - the same thread that runs the UI.  You need to run the HTTP logic inside its own thread instead.  Use the `Thread` class for that. It is a `Runnable` descendant. Call `Thread.start()` instead of `UIApplication.invokeAndWait()`.  Don't have your main code block the event dispatching thread waiting for the thread to finish. Have the thread call `UIApplication.invokeLater()` to signal your main code when it finishes.

Comment: Hi @Remy, I successfully used Thread.start() and it is successfully running in a new thread, but I am unable to make the main thread wait for the new tread ... I am unable to understand hot to utilize UIApplication.invokeLater() in my new thread to signal my main thread.

Comment: You are not supposed to wait.  Let your main code move on to do other things (like processing events) while the thread is running. When the thread is finished, invokeLater() is used to run another piece of code within the main thread.  I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Remy. The issue is fixed.